# My Grunt.JS setup using Google Closure @preserve or @license not working?

Tags: gruntjs, google-closure

Ok, I have grunt.js setup to concat and minify all my JavaScript / Jquery, but for some reason closure just removes the copyright from all but the first file.

Here is my grunt setup

```
   'closure-compiler': {
      frontend: {
         closurePath: '/usr/lib',
         cwd: 'raw_assets/javascript/',
         js: ['jquery-1.11.0.js','bootstrap.js','vars.js','master.js'],
         jsOutputFile: 'assets/output/javascript.js',

         options: {
             compilation_level: 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS',
             language_in: 'ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT',
         }//End of Options 

      } //End of frontend
     }, //End of Closure Compiler
```

Now I have used both @preserve or @license but nothing I do seems the keep the copyright notice in the bootstrap.js file. It works fine on the jquery file but nothing I do seems to keep in my output file for bootstrap, any idea on what I am doing wrong?

All help most welcome,

thanks

Glenn.

Comment: Please, anyone got any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but as a 'temp' fix, I just move the copyright to the JQuery lib. file and is saved within my output file.